# How to define an array with given size from a file?

Tags: java, arrays, file, global

I created a class, and I want to create some global arrays for this class in order to allow all methods of the class to use them.
Problem is I don't know the size of the arrays in the first place.
The size is based upon a file I read using JAVA's code.
How can I define those arrays (Global) with the information I receive from the file?

**Got no problem with reading the file itself and retrieve information from it.

Thanks :)

Comment: Use `List` backed by `ArrayList` instead of array ...

Comment: why dont you try adding setter and getter methods *EDIT* well you wouldnt need a get method if you're only using the variables inside the class itself

Comment: What kind of data do you want to store in your array?

Comment: You can't initialize an empty array, so either you first read the sizes from the file and then initialize the arrays, or you just use `ArrayList`

Comment: @JN11 Actually you can do that. It just won't be helpful here ;)

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**: According to your comment, I had misunderstood your needs.

If your problem is just the array declaration, then this should probably solve it.

You may declare your 2D-array this way as a "global" array(*):

```
private MyClass[][] myArray;
```

This won't initialize it, but declare its type as a 2D-array of `MyClass` objects.

Then when you start reading the file and you've got the size:

```
int size = /* read the size from the file */;
myArray = new MyClass[size][size];
```

---

It is unclear what you want to achieve.

If you want to dynamically add elements to an array and you don't know its size at initialization time, I would suggest you use an `ArrayList`:

```
ArrayList<SomeClassForYourData> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

To add an element:

```
list.add(element);
```

To access element at index `i`:

```
SomeClassForYourData element = list.get(i);
```

To find the size of the structure:

```
int size = list.size();
```

Comment: I wish to define the array/matrix one time, yet the size of the array/matrix is depending on the information given to me in a file.
for example:
in the file its written "n=3"
then i wish to define the size as 3X3 or something like array [n!][n!].
Problem is, I need the matrix to be global matrix, which mean I have to the define it at the top of the class.

Comment: Thank you for your help.
But my problem is that i got a lot of methods in my class which use those global arrays. Meaning, if I define the size in the main method I wont be able to access the arrays(after assigning the size) through other method of the class.